# Cannot pass data to viewController

Tags: swift, navigationcontroller, pass-data

I have two arrays to store area name and website address as string.
In addition, I have 9  area buttons. When you press one of the buttons, it will show a different picture depend on the area button you press.
here is my code:

```
@IBAction func westfjordsBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

    vcContainer[0].address=imgAddress[0]
    vcContainer[0].areaName=areaName[0]
    loadViewIfNeeded()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.vcContainer[0], animated: true)
}
@IBAction func northBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    vcContainer[1].address=imgAddress[1]
    vcContainer[1].areaName=areaName[1]
    loadViewIfNeeded()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.vcContainer[1], animated: true)
}
@IBAction func northeastBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

        vcContainer[2].address=imgAddress[2]
    vcContainer[2].areaName=areaName[2]
    loadViewIfNeeded()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.vcContainer[2], animated: true)
}
@IBAction func eastBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

    vcContainer[3].address=imgAddress[3]
    vcContainer[3].areaName=areaName[3]
    loadViewIfNeeded()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.vcContainer[3], animated: true)
}
@IBAction func southeastBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

        vcContainer[4].address=imgAddress[4]
    vcContainer[4].areaName=areaName[4]
    loadViewIfNeeded()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.vcContainer[4], animated: true)
}
@IBAction func entireBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

        vcContainer[5].address=imgAddress[5]
    vcContainer[5].areaName=areaName[5]
    loadViewIfNeeded()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.vcContainer[5], animated: true)
}
@IBAction func southBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

        vcContainer[6].address=imgAddress[6]
    vcContainer[6].areaName=areaName[6]
    loadViewIfNeeded()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.vcContainer[6], animated: true)
}
@IBAction func westBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

        vcContainer[7].address=imgAddress[7]
    vcContainer[7].areaName=areaName[7]
    loadViewIfNeeded()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.vcContainer[7], animated: true)
}
@IBAction func westsouthBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

        vcContainer[8].address=imgAddress[8]
    vcContainer[8].areaName=areaName[8]
    loadViewIfNeeded()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.vcContainer[8], animated: true)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for i in 0 ..< vcContainer.count {
         vcContainer[i] = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AreaRoadDetailViewController") as! AreaRoadDetailViewController
    }

}
```

However, the code is copied from the first button function, and just change the array index. Only the first button can work correctly, other buttons when I press, it always cannot pass the imgAddress to the AreaRoadDetailViewController.

in the AreaRoadDetailViewController, it always shows the address is nil, but the area name can show correctly. Why so wild? only one button can work! How can I fix it? thank you

Comment: Looks like your problem lies inside the story board

Comment: thank you so much! I delete all the segues then it works!! sorry I'm new in Swift. So I don't know the relationship about segue and navigation! thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have selected all buttons and drag to your `class`, in this way only first button will be set. You have to set a method for each button separately. Check your buttons' links in an inspector. Also remove unnecessary links and methods.